# Symmetrizing Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

For a polynomial $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, we define the operator $T_{\theta, i,j}$ which takes $f$ to $\theta f(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, x_j, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_i, \dots) + (1-\theta) f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.  In words, this is the expected polynomial when one swaps indices $i$ and $j$ with probability $\theta$.  Does there exist a finite sequence of $T_{\theta_k, i_k, j_k}$ such that for any polynomial, the outcome of applying this sequence of operators is the symmetrized polynomial (i.e. the expected polynomial over a uniform distribution of all permutations of the indices)?

Comment: Interesting question! If I had to guess, I'd guess no, since $\frac{1}{n!}$ has an awful lot of primes in the denominator...

Comment: It doesn't even seem obvious for $n=3$. Have you gained any insight from this case? Also, where does this problem arise?

Comment: For $n=2$, switching x and y with probability 1/2 suffices.  For n=3, I can find sequences that work for particular monomials but none that work universally.